# How to obtain data from a dict inside a dict avoiding to use a for loop in python

Tags: performance, dictionary, for-loop, python-3.9

Data example:

```
response = {
  "took" : value1,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 150,
    },
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "date1",
          "hit" : 1,
          "routing-key" : "id_key1",
          "data": vector1[0:299] 
        },
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index2",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "date2",
          "hit" : 2,
          "routing-key" : "id_key2",
          "data": vector2[0:299] 
        },
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index3",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "date3",
          "hit" : 3,
          "routing-key" : "id_key3",
          "data": vector3[0:299] 
        },
      },
#...
# I am not going to copy the whole request but there are until 150 hits
#...
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I want to get the value of the "data": vector[0:299] in the position 120 from all the hits in the request

I have try to do

```
vect_sol = response['hits']['hits'][:]['_source']['data'][120]
```

But I get the error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

To get the indexs in the 'hit' dict I have used

```
vect_sol = response['hits']['hits'][:]
```

and it works. So how I have gotten the  required value inside the data vector with a `for` loop

```
for i in range(hits):
   data_sol[i] = response['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['data'][120]
```

This works fine but when the request of data is made of 10,000 hits or more (can be even larger) the script takes time to fill the `data_sol` vector.

I am guessing if there is some function or a different way to obtain the data as requestes but cutting the execution time of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python **comprehension lists** to that (although this could be considered as a loop):

```py
vect_sol = [item['_source']['data'][120] for item in response['hits']['hits']]
```

If you do not need to iterate over the full data structure you can use Python **generators** (that are lazy):

```py
vect_sol = (item['_source']['data'][120] for item in response['hits']['hits'])
```

Alternatively, you can use a more functional-oriented code (probably faster) with **`map`**:

```py
vect_sol = map(lambda item: item['_source']['data'][120], response['hits']['hits'])
```

If you want a faster code, I think you should convert you data structure to interrelated objects (of well-defined classes). This should be much faster than using Python dictionaries (which are hash-map) with string keys (which need to be hashed).

Comment: Thanks Jérôme, but as you said this can be consideres as a loop. What I am looking is to replace the loop for some functions if possible. Thanks again

Comment: Ok. I edited the post to add another version. I do not think you can do better in pure Python. But external packages could do interesting things for you. More specifically, you can give a look to the Python packages implementing [LINKQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) in Python (like [this one](https://viralogic.github.io/py-enumerable/) for example).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jérôme the py_linq library helped a lot. I have avoid the loop and the code runs faster :)